# why chrome rotate a image and firefox not

Tags: image, wordpress

I am working on wordpress, and I have rotate a image with the media editor, but I am seeing that the image is rotate only on chrome, but not in firefox

by example

```
http://174.122.148.250/~macabee/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Pottery-5.jpg

http://174.122.148.250/~macabee/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/21-1024x576.jpg
```

these images are not rotated on firefox

can you tell me why could be? and what can I do to see it rotate on both browser

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These images are "technically" sideways. Rotating an image can be done in one of two ways.

The first way is to write a piece of information to the metadata of the file that says that the image should be shown rotated. It seems that only Chrome understands this method.

The second way to rotate is to actually rewrite the order of the pixels. Essentially, the pixels in the leftmost column of pixels will be put at the top of the image. The next row will be placed below that -- you're actually changing the image.

Right now your images seem to be 'rotated' using the first method. You may need to use a different program to rotate your original images.

Comment: On my copy of Firefox 22 for Mac, those images are properly rotated so it looks like Firefox now interprets that metadata. Still, it's best to rotate the images the second way in order to ensure that all browsers old and new properly display the image as being rotated.

Comment: Interesting article about this problem with practical tests: http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/

Comment: Wow. This is nasty. I spend way too much time looking in my CSS to find the problem. More people should be aware of this. THANKS!